# Wicket: ListView not updated when using multiple browser windows in simple CRUD

Tags: java, listview, wicket, crud

Ok, here is my controller using Wicket 1.5M2:

```
public class Users extends WebPage {

private static final List<User> users = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<User>());

public Users() {

    final UserForm userForm = new UserForm("userForm");
    add(userForm);

    add(new ListView<User>("users", users) {

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> item) {
            final User user = item.getModelObject();

            item.add(new Label("name", user.getName()));
            item.add(DateLabel.forDatePattern("dateOfBirth", new Model(user.getDateOfBirth()), "dd.MM.yyyy"));
            item.add(new Label("email", user.getEmail()));

            item.add(new Link("editLink") {

                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    userForm.setModelObject(user);
                }

            });

            item.add(new Link("removeLink") {

                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    users.remove(user);
                }

            });
        }

    });

    setVersioned(false);
}

private class UserForm extends Form<User> {

    public UserForm(String id) {
        super(id, new CompoundPropertyModel<User>(new User()));

        add(new TextField<String>("name"));
        add(DateTextField.forDatePattern("dateOfBirth", "dd.MM.yyyy"));
        add(new TextField<String>("email"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit() {
        User user = getModelObject();
        users.remove(user);
        users.add(user);
        setModelObject(new User());
    }
}
}
```

It works when I use only one browser window at a time for CRUD operations. If I use two windows, the list of users does not update, unless I input the base address again to the address field to reload the page.

CLARIFICATION: Using different browsers simultaneously in same computer works good. Only when using multiple windows in same browser it does not work.

- What is happening behind the scenes?
- I set setVersioned(false) for the whole page, why is it that my address bar shows addresses like: http://localhost:8080/wicket/bookmarkable/package.name.Users?2
  Isn't that number 2 the version of the page?
- Most importantly what do I need to do to make this behave like a desktop GUI app, so one browser window == one instance of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your main issue, but `setVersioned(false)` does exactly what you think it does and appears to be working. Whatever the 2 is, it's not the Wicket page version number; if it were, the 2 would have come after a period, not a question mark.

Check out this page about versioning, specifically not displaying version numbers: [Wicket extreme consistent URLs](http://day-to-day-stuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/wicket-extreme-consistent-urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) In your implementation there is a statefull page, and yes, "?2" is a version of the page. You can check it by opening new tabs, or submiting form - this number will increase.

When you opens new tab in the same browser, actually you are using the same session. WebApp thinks that you are the same user on the previous tab and creates another version of the page.

Now, if you submit some information in new tab, than it will be ok, but if you return on previous tab and submit some info - Wicket detects, that this version of the page is deprecated and starts to search actual version. For some reason your POST info looses at this time.

2) To get rid of the page version you need to set your page stateless. To do that you need to make your links and form stateless : just replace them by `StatelessLink` and `StatelessForm` objects. Additionally, set your page `setStatelessHint ( true );` and now your tabs will work correctlly and without versions. Developer [example](http://martin-g.github.io/wicket-reference-guide/stateless.html).

3) This is not normal behavior, and you need to manage browser's cookies. More about this [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Creating-a-new-session-if-new-browser-tab-is-opened-td1868974.html#a1868975).